# Javascript: change first child style

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I would like to **change the color** of the `<span>` tag, when clicking on the containing `<td>`:

```
<td onClick='myfunc(this)'>
    <span class='spanClass'>text</span>
</td>
```

what should the `myfunc` be like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set *element.style.color* inside the function.

If you have single child then you can use [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) property of the current element.  If you have multiple children and you want to set the *color* to all of them then you have to iterate over all the children to set the *color*.

```js
function myfunc(el){
  el.firstElementChild.style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onClick='myfunc(this)'>
        <span class='spanClass'>text</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I would like to change the style of the child, not of the `td`. How can I reference a sibling even if it doesn't have an `id`?

Comment: @DanieleB, sibling of what??

Comment: in your code example, it would be the style of the `a` tag

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I meant "child", not "sibling"

Comment: @DanieleB, to set all the child's style you have to use loop....if there is only one child you can use `firstElementChild` like I did in the answer......thanks.

Comment: Great! `firstElementChild` was exactly what I was looking for! many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for  js

```
function changeColor(el) {        
  el.querySelector('span.spanclass').style.setProperty('color', 'red');
}
```

try this one for jquery

```
$(this).find('.spanclass').css({"color":"red")
```

or

```
$(this).find('span').css({"color":"red")
```

for more  [details](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_find.asp)

Comment: This would require JsQuery. I am looking for a standard Javascript solution.